# Parse HTML in PHP and return JSON

Tags: php, html, json, parsing, dom

I am using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) in my PHP script to parse information from a website into a JSON object. My JSON object should be formatted like this in the end:

Array with maximum 5 objects (Monday to Friday) or less (Tuesday–Friday etc).

All of these objects should have two arrays, one called `food1` and one called `food 2`. Both of these arrays should contain multiple food names and their prices. I think in JSON it would look like this:

```
    {
  "day" : [
    {
      "food1" : [
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        },
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        }
      ],
      "food2" : [
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        },
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "food1" : [
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        },
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        }
      ],
      "food2" : [
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        },
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "food1" : [
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        },
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        }
      ],
      "food2" : [
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        },
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "food1" : [
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        },
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        }
      ],
      "food2" : [
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        },
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "food1" : [
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        },
        {
          "price" : "1.00",
          "foodname" : "test"
        }
      ],
      "food2" : [
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        },
        {
          "price" : "2.00",
          "foodname" : "test2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyway I previously only worked with Objective-C and having problems with solving this problem in PHP. I have also implemented a parser in Objective-C that works, but if the site changes their structure I would have to re-submit the whole app etc. That’s why I wanted to make a web service where I can dynamically change the parser outside of the app. All I got is this:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_html('http://www.studentenwerk-karlsruhe.de/de/essen/?view=ok&STYLE=popup_plain&c=erzberger&p=1&kw=3',false,$context);

foreach($html->find('b') as $e) 
    echo $e;

?>
```

Which gives me all the food names but it isn’t sorted for the days and also not for the different food menus (there are two different menus on each day which are called `food1` and `food2` in my example JSON object).

In my Objective-C parser I just created a new day object when the food name is “SchniPoSa” and added all the following food names to `food1` until there comes the food name “Salatbuffet” that and all the following food names I added to `food2` array until there comes the next “SchniPoSa” food name. But this isn’t very good because the structure could change every day.

Also, I do not even know how to implement that in PHP. In my little PHP script I also don’t parse all the prices which are in the tag `<span class="bgp price_1">`.

Here is the website from which I want to parse the information:

http://www.studentenwerk-karlsruhe.de/de/essen/?view=ok&STYLE=popup_plain&c=erzberger&p=1&kw=3

Is there anyone who can help me with parsing the information in a valid JSON object like I described below?

Comment: If the site changes it's layout in anyway you will have to change your code, there can be no "final" version using this method..

Comment: of course but i could change the code on my php webservice. I would not (depends on the change) have to change my objective-c code. Therefore i would not have to submit an app update everytime there is a little change. Also this way i could make the webservice public to some people who might want to access the information also..

Comment: that is true, you could have a web-service that just standardizes the return object.. will look into a class and come back to you later on..

Comment: got any hint for me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just saw you message and realised I hadn't gotten back to you about this.
Maybe this will lead you in the right direction:

```
<?php

$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.studentenwerk-karlsruhe.de/de/essen/?view=ok&STYLE=popup_plain&c=erzberger&p=1&kw=3',false,$context);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//table[@class='easy-tab-dot']");
//header("Content-type: text/plain");

foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    $arr = array();

    $children = $node->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
        $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));       
        #echo $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
        print_r( $child );
    }
    echo "#######################################################################################";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! So basically 1 DomObject represents one of the tables. So i already have the breakdown of the 2 menus per day. Basically all i have to do now is to add the information from the DomObjects in json objects. Thanks :)