# Use PHP and cURL to pull JSON data from mixed text / html / javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

Using PHP and cURL on [THIS](http://flyers.shoppersdrugmart.ca/flyers/shoppersdrugmart?type=2&locale=en) link, returns a file containing information similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            window['flyerData'] = {
                "id":489640,
                "categories":[{
                    "id":527,
                    "flyer_category_id":1201344,
                    "run_category_id":null,
                    "skipped":null,
                    "name":"Pharmacy",
                    "left":2925.0,
                    "bottom":-2560.0,
                    "right":4388.0,
                    "top":0.0,
                    "thumbnail_image_url":null
                }]
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the results are mixed html / javascript. What I would like to do is work with `window['flyerData']` so I can filter the values as I wish.

How does one go about this using PHP and cURL?

Comment: The file that you are requesting with cURL is under your control? Can you modify it in any way?

Comment: Do you have access to create and execute Node.JS scripts on your server?

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez Nope, the file is not under my control, it's a scrape.

Comment: @TbWill4321 I'm not familiar with Node.JS.. yet. What did you have in mind?

Comment: The Node.JS runtime lets you execute JS scripts from shell ( and loads more ).  You could have PHP call the shell script, pass the contents as an argument, and respond with a `JSON.stringify`ed version to work with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse HTML in PHP and return JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160760/parse-html-in-php-and-return-json)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (untested):

```
<?php
    //get the contents of the curl call
    $curlOutput = "<!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                            <head></head>
                            <body>
                                <script>
                                    window['flyerData'] = {
                                        "id":489640,
                                        "categories":[{
                                            "id":527,
                                            "flyer_category_id":1201344,
                                            "run_category_id":null,
                                            "skipped":null,
                                            "name":"Pharmacy",
                                            "left":2925.0,
                                            "bottom":-2560.0,
                                            "right":4388.0,
                                            "top":0.0,
                                            "thumbnail_image_url":null
                                        }]
                                    }
                                </script>
                            </body>
                        </html>";
    //strip out everything except for the values between the first '{' and the last '}'
    $json = substr($curlOutput, stripos($curlOutput, '{'), strripos($curlOutput, '}'));
    //parse that string as JSON
    $decodedJson = json_decode($json);
    var_dump(decodedJson);
    var_dump(decodedJson.categories);
?>
```

But note that this type of parsing is considered to be fragile since the format of the string from the `curl` call is not guaranteed to continue to conform to the HTML/JS that it does today. This is why a well defined API is a better choice if you have access to one.

Comment: It might be a little more complicated than that. There are many script tags within the results. You'll see if you view the source. I know that `window['flyerData']` is constant every time, and that's all I need to work with.

Comment: Your complexity is only in parsing a string to get the values you desire. You can change the start position to be the index of the string `window['flyerData'] = {`, then look at the string between that index and the first occurrence of `</script>`. I'm sure there are a lot of regex examples out there that will help you.

Comment: Your solution was close but your second `stripos` returned the index of the first `"}"` found in the entire file, not the first one found in the context I was searching in. Turns out there was already a `"}"` earlier on in the file. This resulted in the final output being cut short. If it was the only `"}"` in the entire file, your solution would have been perfect, so I'll give you a point ;)

I ended up using this:
 `preg_match('/window\[\'flyerData\'\] = (\{.*\}\;)/',  $responseBody, $matches);
echo $matches[1];`

Which worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for pulling the string I wanted:

```
preg_match('/window\[\'flyerData\'\] \= (\{.*\};)/', $responseBody, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```